# I believe there is a “serial spammer”

Tags: discussion, spam

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/4834256/user311488) has accounts on [6 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/users/4834256/user311488?tab=accounts). They joined every single one today.

I can't see deleted questions, but we did just delete a question they posted offering loans on ask ubuntu - [here is the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505818/no-credit-check-loans-http-www-nsnocreditcheckloans-co-uk) that 10k+ users will be able to see. They may have also been spamming these sites, but I can't see deleted questions.

Comment: Just flag such posts as spam; the system can extrapolate from that and handle similar spam network wide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flagging the posts as SPAM is the thing to do on every SPAM post of that account across the network. (I've accounts on a lot of sites just for that reason).

You can always drop in a [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) to organize some more SPAM flags if needed.

There is no need to do anything else, so leave no comments and foremost don't edit the post.

With enough SPAM flags the account will be come useless (due to the -100 rep) and will be nuked.

The FAQ reference on [spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) holds some extra/in-depth guidance.